# How can I enable packet forwarding on Windows?

Tags: windows

In the Linux system, we can use bellow command to enable packets forwarding:

```
~ # sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

but how can I realize the same function in Windows?

I use `Windows Server 2008 R2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to go to the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`. If not already there, create a new `REG_DWORD` value named `IPEnableRouter`. Set `IPEnableRouter` to `1` and reboot. Packet forwarding should now be enabled.

To add static routes use the `route` command.

Comment: https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-howto-enable-ip-routing

Answer (score 24):

If you want to enable forwarding for a specific interface or all interfaces you can do it easily from PowerShell, no reboot required.  (NOTE: be sure to run as an Administrator if you want to change the setting)

To look at the status of forwarding for all interfaces you can execute the following:

```
Get-NetIPInterface | select ifIndex,InterfaceAlias,AddressFamily,ConnectionState,Forwarding | Sort-Object -Property IfIndex | Format-Table
```

This will provide a nice table showing all the interfaces and their current forwarding configuration.

Then if you want to enable forwarding on one you can run:

```
Set-NetIPInterface -ifindex <required interface index from table> -Forwarding Enabled
```

If you want to enable it for all interfaces simply run:

```
Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled
```

Then if you want to disable it again simply replace "Enabled" with "Disabled".

And remember to enable **Routing and Remote Access service** (By default is disabled) by running:

```
Set-Service RemoteAccess -StartupType Automatic; Start-Service RemoteAccess
```

Comment: When I run the `Get-NetIPInterface` in PowerShell, I get cannot recognition command Error.

Comment: Try running: Import-Module NetTCPIP

Comment: Let me know if that works and I'll update the answer

Comment: PS C:\Users\Administrator> Import-Module NetTCPIP
Import-Module : Can not load module“NetTCPIP”，because can not find it...

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: windows server 2008.

Comment: Ah, an important piece of detail. For such an old version this won't work unfortunately. Windows Server 2012 or newer introduced this module. Sorry about that, although I would recommend upgrading!

Comment: Its alright, bro..