# Windows routes through wrong interface

Tags: windows, routing, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 21H1. There are several networks connected to my machine. I've noticed I cannot ping hosts in 192.168.3.* network. Here's my routing table:

```
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.126     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.126    281
    192.168.0.126  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.126    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.126    281
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.80    281
     192.168.1.80  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.80    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.80    281
      192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.3.86    281
     192.168.3.86  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.3.86    281
    192.168.3.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.3.86    281
    192.168.117.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.117.1    291
    192.168.117.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.117.1    291
  192.168.117.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.117.1    291
    192.168.232.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.232.1    291
    192.168.232.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.232.1    291
  192.168.232.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.232.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.232.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.117.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.80    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.3.86    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.126    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.232.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.117.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.80    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.3.86    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.126    281
```

This is the output of `tracert -d 192.168.3.19`:

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2    33 ms    14 ms    24 ms  192.168.8.1
  3  ^C
```

As you can see, it's routing through the wrong interface. Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

UPD. I expect it to route the packet directly to 192.168.3.19 because of this line in the routing table:

`192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.3.86    281`

Doesn't it say "for all nodes of 192.168.3.0 network, route packets to them directly"? 192.168.3.86 is the IP address of my machine.

Comment: Is it possible that 192.168.3.86 is down and Dead Gateway Detection feature is enabled on the Windows 10 machine?

Comment: No, 192.168.3.86 is my machine's IP.

Comment: My bad, got confused. Please update your question with routing behavior you are expecting. Currently I can't see any other routes for 192.168.3.0/24, apart the default one. So it is working as intended

Comment: Updated, please take a look. My understanding is that there is a route for 192.168.3.0/24 in the routing table, so the default route should not apply here.

Comment: My guess would be the 192.168.8.1 is returned from your default router. Try adding the IPEnableRouter registry value.  https://serverfault.com/questions/929081/how-can-i-enable-packet-forwarding-on-windows